# When adding Text - TextMeshPro in the inspector some of the components overlap the others. if there a way to repair that?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using unity editor version 2019.4.15f1 personal and i didn't try it yet on newer editor version.

In the TextMeshPro inspector i can't see the transform part i cant see other components and some components overlap other components.

Screenshot of the Canvas :

[image: Canvas]

The textmeshpro :

[image: TextMeshPro]

I tried now with editor version 2020.3.28f1 personal the problem is now fixed but now i can't see the text anywhere there is written New Test but in the scene view and game view the text is empty.

Not sure if changing to new editor version fixed the first problem and how to fix the new problem that the text is not shown now.

Comment: So, this is a common issue with Unity. A workaround is to collapse all the components and acces them one by one. Here are also some other links:
[1](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1782924/inspector-window-has-parts-clipping-inside-of-itin.html)
[2](https://forum.unity.com/threads/2019-1-9f1-inspector-overlapping-bug.717119/)
[3](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1828499/nested-class-lists-inspector-overlapping-bug.html)
[4](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/scriptableobject-with-an-array-of-serializable-classes-with-arrays-in-them-is-overlapping-in-the-inspector-when-expanded)